# Multiple Python versions in Debian

Tags: python, debian, version, deprecated

Im trying to manage multiple python versions in Debian 8, Python 2.7 (default) and 2.6. The problem is, i dont now how to do correctly for installing modules in the 2.6 version. pip is deprecated for 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

> [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) is a tool to create isolated Python environments.
>
> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions,
>   and indirectly permissions. Imagine you have an application that needs
>   version 1 of LibFoo, but another application requires version 2. How
>   can you use both these applications? If you install everything into
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (or whatever your platform’s standard
>   location is), it’s easy to end up in a situation where you
>   unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn’t be upgraded.
>
> Or more generally, what if you want to install an application and
>   leave it be? If an application works, any change in its libraries or
>   the versions of those libraries can break the application.
>
> Also, what if you can’t install packages into the global site-packages
>   directory? For instance, on a shared host.
>
> In all these cases, virtualenv can help you. It creates an environment
>   that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share
>   libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t
>   access the globally installed libraries either).